# Find and remove longest string within string in each row of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I have a csv file that I am importing to a pandas dataframe. Here is an example of the data in one of the columns. Each value between the delimiters is a "tag" that I would to use. I also have values that I do not want to use as a tag...these values are the "long" ones, essentially a product description of sorts, and not a tag.

```
Anthropologie Dolan Women's S Green Long Sleeves Tie Front Dress\,Girl\, Woman\, USA\, American\, Chic
Button\,Logo\,Blue Skinny Crop Denim Raw Hem Ankle Denim Jeans
```

I first get a replace done to have the proper delimter that I need (i get a list of columns I need to apply this to from a config file):

```
for col in config["wooAttributeReplace"]:
    woo_product_list[col] = woo_product_list[col].replace(r'\\,', '|', regex=True)
```

and get this:

```
Anthropologie Dolan Women's S Green Long Sleeves Tie Front Dress|Girl| Woman| USA| American| Chic
Button|Logo|Blue Skinny Crop Denim Raw Hem Ankle Denim Jeans
```

My final output would look like this:

```
Girl | Woman | USA | American | Chic
Button | Logo
```

I originally thought that the "long" product description sections were always first so I tried this:

```
woo_product_list[col].mask(woo_product_list[col].str.len() > 40, woo_product_list[col].str.split('|', n=1).str.get(-1), inplace=True)
which led to this:
```

```
Girl| Woman| USA| American| Chic
Logo|Blue Skinny Crop Denim Raw Hem Ankle Denim Jeans
```

but that is not really the right solution for multiple scenarios (i.e. the product string is not first) and what I think I am trying to do now is to "find the longest string within the string (between a | delimiter) and remove it. Hopefully this makes enough sense and if anyone has any tips I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have the tags mixed into the same field of the CSV? The whole point of using CSV format is to seprarate values into appropriate fields.

Comment: This is source data that I cannot change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to split the string by `,` and then remove the longest string from the list.

Suppose you have this dataframe:

```
                                                                                             Column1
0  Anthropologie Dolan Women's S Green Long Sleeves Tie Front Dress,Girl, Woman, USA, American, Chic
1                                       Button,Logo,Blue Skinny Crop Denim Raw Hem Ankle Denim Jeans
```

Then

```py
# make attributes column
df["Attributes"] = df["Column1"].apply(lambda x: list(map(str.strip, x.split(","))))

# remove longest string
df["Attributes"] = df["Attributes"].apply(
    lambda x: [v for m in [max(x, key=len)] for v in x if v != m]
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                                                                             Column1                          Attributes
0  Anthropologie Dolan Women's S Green Long Sleeves Tie Front Dress,Girl, Woman, USA, American, Chic  [Girl, Woman, USA, American, Chic]
1                                       Button,Logo,Blue Skinny Crop Denim Raw Hem Ankle Denim Jeans                      [Button, Logo]
```

---

EDIT:

```py
# make attributes column
df["Attributes"] = df["Column1"].apply(lambda x: list(map(str.strip, x.split(","))))

# remove longest string
mask = df["Attributes"].str.len() != 1

df["Attributes"] = np.where(
    mask,
    df["Attributes"].apply(
        lambda x: [v for m in [max(x, key=len)] for v in x if len(v) < 10 or v != m]
    ),
    df["Attributes"],
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                                                                             Column1                          Attributes
0  Anthropologie Dolan Women's S Green Long Sleeves Tie Front Dress,Girl, Woman, USA, American, Chic  [Girl, Woman, USA, American, Chic]
1                                       Button,Logo,Blue Skinny Crop Denim Raw Hem Ankle Denim Jeans                      [Button, Logo]
2                                                                                             Button                            [Button]
3                                                                                   Button1, Button2                  [Button1, Button2]
```

Comment: This works great except one caveat I failed to mention. In some cases row may only have 1 simple tag: (say: Button) It does not also have the "Product Description" as I mentioned easlier...so in these cases I would like to keep that tag i.e. "Button" In all these cases, if there was an individual tag present, it would be short, say 10  characters or less. Is there a way to keep the tag if it is say 10 characters or less?

Comment: @JCan I've updated my answer.

Comment: Awesome, any way to make this a string again?

Comment: @JCan Probably `df["Attributes"] = df["Attributes"].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x))`